# Render a scene using more than one camera simultaneously

Tags: python, rendering, eevee-render-engine

I'm Trying to render with two cameras simultaneously, using EEVEE but when I play the code my Blender crash.

Use a loop to render camera by camera demands much time, and there's a bunch of keyframes

I could open 2 Blenders to do this but I want to make something that I can use in only one cause the scene uses much Ram and open two Blender eat much memory of my PC.

This is a example of the code that I made:

```
import bpy
import concurrent.futures as cf

def Loop():
    bpy.context.scene.render.engine = "BLENDER_EEVEE"
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = 512
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = 512
    bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = "PNG"

    bpy.context.scene.frame_start = 1
    bpy.context.scene.frame_end = 10

    camera_names = [bpy.data.objects["Camera"], bpy.data.objects["Camera.001"]]

    def Rendering(camera):
        for frame in range(bpy.context.scene.frame_start, bpy.context.scene.frame_end + 1):

            bpy.context.scene.camera = camera

            filepath = f"/Test/{camera}_%01d.png" % frame

            bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)
            bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = filepath
            bpy.ops.render.render(write_still = True)

    with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 2) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(Rendering, camera_name) for camera_name in camera_names]
        for future in cf.as_completed(futures):
            result = future.result()

Loop()
```

The error:

```
Writing: /tmp/Test.crash.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: The crash is definitely caused by a threading issue. it's generally not recommended to call Blender operators, including `bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer`, from a separate thread. This is because Blender's user interface and internal state are not designed to be accessed or modified from multiple threads simultaneously.

Comment: The Blender still crashing after I change the ``bpy.ops.wm.redraw_time``

Comment: as i have mentioned in my previous comment it is not recommended to call `bpy.ops` operators from separate threads. there is still `bpy.ops.render.render`.  try commenting it out and see if it still crashes.

Comment: It still crashing even if i comment render ``bpy.ops.render.render``

Comment: yes. also functions like `bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)` will crash it because they are not [thread safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). You need to find another way.

Comment: I made a code that render using two scenes at the same time, I will share here to them see